# How to place textView on top of the recycler view?

Tags: android

I have a recyclerView (Shimmer RecyclerView) and a fab. I need to display a description for my fab but when I place a textView in the xml file, the textView is displayed behind the recyclerView while I need it on top of the recyclerView. Any idea how to achieve the disired result?

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_gray_rounded"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="someText"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            app:shimmer_demo_angle="35"
            app:shimmer_demo_child_count="10"
            app:shimmer_demo_layout_manager_type="linear_vertical"
            app:shimmer_demo_reverse_animation="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoordinatorLayout` extends from `FrameLayout`, so the child `View`s are stacked each on top of the previous one (with the `FloatingActionButton` as an exception because this `View` specifically is managed by the `CoordinatorLayout`).

So you need to swap the `TextView` and the `RecyclerView` to achieve the desired effect (at least it works with a "normal" `RecyclerView`)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        app:shimmer_demo_angle="35"
        app:shimmer_demo_child_count="10"
        app:shimmer_demo_layout_manager_type="linear_vertical"
        app:shimmer_demo_reverse_animation="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_gray_rounded"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="someText"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    app:shimmer_demo_angle="35"
    app:shimmer_demo_child_count="10"
    app:shimmer_demo_layout_manager_type="linear_vertical"
    app:shimmer_demo_reverse_animation="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_gray_rounded"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="someText"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

I have tried this. It works same as you wish in question. I Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

organise your fab and textView in a separate layout, and include that in your coordinatorLayout

Comment: glad you got it fixed!